# How do I realign web part zones?

Tags: web-part-zone

I have three web part zones that are arranged in columns (Left) (Middle) and (Right) underneath one long Header Zone... The Left and Right zones are lined up to the Header zone, but the Middle Zone is not.  It looks like there's a big gap between the Middle Zone and Header Zone.  How do I shift the Middle Zone up so that it's in line with the Left and Right Zones?

Comment: It's difficult to say without actually seeing it. My first instinct is there's a remnant of some div from another web part that was deleted at some point, and you might have to edit the XML to clean it up. Which version of SP? What's the history of the page (did you just make it or are you editing an old one)? Do you use the browser to edit things, or do you have/know SP Designer? Do you have any experience with XML? Is the web part custom or OOB? Your best bet is using SPD to examine it, if you haven't already. You should be able to spot the problem and remove the offending code.

Comment: Open the page in SharePoint Designer and see if there is any extra space between the two Web Part Zones!